# Writing a piecewise function

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image]

I stuck to write the above piecewise function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could nest a couple of `rcases` environments inside a `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'rcases' env.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\begin{document}
\[
k(x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{rcases}
\phantom{-}x+3, & -3\le x\le -2\\
-x-1, & -2\le x\le -1\\
0,     & \phantom{-}\text{otherwise}
\end{rcases} \text{if $k=n^2$} \\
\\[-1.5ex]
\begin{rcases}
\phantom{-}x-1, & \phantom{-}1\le x\le 2\phantom{-} \\
-x+3, & \phantom{-}2\le x\le 3 \\
0,     & \phantom{-}\text{otherwise}
\end{rcases} \text{if $k\ne n^2$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```